# JSF converter causes validator(s) to be ignored

Tags: java, jsf-2

Here's the field:

```
<h:inputText id="mobilePhoneNo"
             value="#{newPatientBean.phoneNo}"
             required="true"
             requiredMessage="Required"
             validator="#{mobilePhoneNumberValidator}"
             validatorMessage="Not valid (validator)"
             converter="#{mobilePhoneNumberConverter}"
             converterMessage="Not valid (converter)"
             styleClass="newPatientFormField"/>
```

And the validator:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class MobilePhoneNumberValidator implements Validator, Serializable
{
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) throws ValidatorException
    {
        // This will appear in the log if/when this method is called.
        System.out.println("mobilePhoneNumberValidator.validate()");

        UIInput in = (UIInput) uic;
        String value = in.getSubmittedValue() != null ? in.getSubmittedValue().toString().replace("-", "").replace(" ", "") : "";

        if (!value.matches("04\\d{8}"))
        {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Please enter a valid mobile phone number.", null));
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the command button within the form, I get the following behaviour:

- When the field is blank, the message is "Not valid (converter)".
- When the field has a valid entry, the message is "Not valid (validator)".
- When the field has an invalid entry, the message is "Not valid (converter)".

In all three cases, `MobilePhoneNumberConverter.getAsObject()` is called. `MobilePhoneNumberValidator.validate()` is **never** called. And when the field is blank, it ignores the `required="true"` attribute and proceeds straight to conversion.

I would have thought the proper behaviour would be:

- When the field is blank, the message should be "Required".
- When the field has a valid entry, there should be no message at all.
- When the field has an invalid entry, the message should be "Not valid (validator)".
- If, by some chance, validation passed by conversion didn't, the message should be "Not valid (converter)".

Note: The backing bean is request scoped, so there's no fancy AJAX business going on here.

**Update:**

Might it have something to do with `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` being set to `true`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Conversion happens before validation. Converters will also be called when the value is `null` or empty. If you want to delegate the `null` value to the validators, then you need to design your converters that it just returns `null` when the supplied value is `null` or empty.

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your validator has a flaw. You should not extract the submitted value from the component. It's **not** the same value as returned by the converter. The right submitted and converted value is available as the 3rd method argument already.

```
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value == null) {
        return; // This should normally not be hit when required="true" is set.
    }

    String phoneNumber = (String) value; // You need to cast it to the same type as returned by Converter, if any.

    if (!phoneNumber.matches("04\\d{8}")) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Please enter a valid mobile phone number.", null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Despite coming in much later and basically summarising the long conversation attached to βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ's answer (which I had accepted), I'd much rather the most useful answer be the one marked as accepted for the benefit of others who come across this question. Sorry βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ :(

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that I updated the answer after having a closer look at your validator implementation which is essentially wrong as well.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for correcting me. Since, totally misleading I am editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for the validation correction. It's all quite clear now. The converter converts so the validator doesn't have to. That leave's the validator to check that the already-converted value is within some sort of acceptable range. I guess I'm confusing the concept of convertibility (i.e. Is the string parameter a valid representation of an object type of type X) with validation (i.e. Does the object (not the string representation of it, which is already assumed valid) have a valid state for a particular usage?

Comment: The converter is merely to change the submitted String value to a different object type (or to a String in a different representation). If the converter cannot do its conversion job for whatever reason, then it should throw a `ConverterException`. The validator is merely to check if the submitted and converted object is allowed to be processed. E.g. a certain length, range, value, etc. In case of a phone number, a converter is at highest only useful to trim leading/trailing whitespace and a validator is useful to validate the syntax/format. If invalid, a `ValidatorException` must be thrown.

Comment: And I just found out `converter` is an instance expression whereas `validator` is a method expression.  >slaps head<

Answer (score 4):

After reading BalusC's comment I am updating this post again.

I created a small demo application and to see the phases and when the conversion and validation occur.

View:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{demoBean.field}">
        <f:converter converterId="demoConverter"/>
        <f:validator validatorId="demoValidator"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{demoBean.demoAxn()}"/>
</h:form>
```

Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DemoBean implements Serializable {
    private String field;

    public DemoBean() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
    }

    public String getField() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String demoAxn() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value="demoConverter")
public class DemoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);            
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
        return (String) value;
    }    
}
```

Validator:

```
@FacesValidator(value="demoValidator")
public class DemoValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
    }

}
```

Phase listener:

```
public class DemoPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
        System.out.println("PhaseId: " + event.getPhaseId() + "  ===============================\n\n");        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("\n\nPhaseId: " + event.getPhaseId() + "  ===============================");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);        
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }    
}
```

Registered the phase listener:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>pkg.DemoPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

With that setting when the "Submit" button is clicked, the output is:

```
INFO: PhaseId: RESTORE_VIEW 1  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: RESTORE_VIEW 1  ===============================

INFO: PhaseId: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2  ===============================

INFO: PhaseId: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoConverter.getAsObject(DemoConverter.java:13)
INFO: pkg.DemoValidator.validate(DemoValidator.java:14)
INFO: pkg.DemoBean.getField(DemoBean.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3  ===============================

INFO: PhaseId: UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoBean.setField(DemoBean.java:22)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4  ===============================

INFO: PhaseId: INVOKE_APPLICATION 5  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoBean.demoAxn(DemoBean.java:27)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: INVOKE_APPLICATION 5  ===============================

INFO: PhaseId: RENDER_RESPONSE 6  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoBean.getField(DemoBean.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoConverter.getAsString(DemoConverter.java:20)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: RENDER_RESPONSE 6  ===============================
```

But when make change to throw a NPE in the converter as follows:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);            
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

the output is:

```
INFO: PhaseId: RESTORE_VIEW 1  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: RESTORE_VIEW 1  ===============================

INFO: PhaseId: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2  ===============================

INFO: PhaseId: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3  ===============================
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.beforePhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:17)
INFO: pkg.DemoConverter.getAsObject(DemoConverter.java:13)
INFO: pkg.DemoPhaseListener.afterPhase(DemoPhaseListener.java:10)
INFO: PhaseId: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3  ===============================

INFO: pkg.DemoBean.getField(DemoBean.java:17)
```

But the stacktrace is displayed on the resulting view.

Comment: I don't know what's going on here... I changed the converters and validators to being annotated the JSF 2.0 way. There was a time not so long ago when this made absolutely no difference. Perhaps GlassFish 3.1.1 is screwing with me. Anyway, with the "correct" annotations the `required` attribute is still not working, instead going straight to conversion. In fact, there is absolutely no scenario now in which validation occurs. Should I take this to mean that converters cause validation to be skipped?

Comment: "Should I take this to mean that converters cause validation to be skipped?" No. They do different unrelated stuffs, and we should be able to run them together. But, in case of a failure jsf stops request processing and skips other phase and jumps to render response.'

Comment: "No. They do different unrelated stuffs, and we should be able to run them together." I'm seeing it with my own eyes - they are **not** working together. "But, in case of a failure jsf stops request processing and skips other phase and jumps to render response." How is this relevant, though? Validation and conversion occur in the same phase and jsf will at least run this phase to completion (to validate *all* the submitted values and therefore show *all* the validation/conversion errors) before skipping the remaining phases.

Comment: Conversion happens in the "Apply Request Values" phase whereas validation takes place in "Process Validation" phase.

Comment: Check doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html

Comment: Ok, I found a different doc that said basically the same thing. It means I have to modify my converters such that they gracefully handle `null` input. I'll let you know in a few moments how that turns out. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it was 100% my misunderstanding of the lifecycle and 0% your original answer. And to prove the 0% part, I reverted back to having my converters' and validators' lifecycles managed by CDI and it works just fine. So if you either edit this answer or add a new one I will accept it.

Comment: You're confusing EL-coercion with JSF conversion. EL-coercion runs during apply request values phase and JSF conversion runs during validations phase, right before the JSF validation.