# Is there a way to update component even when JSF fail during Process Validation phase

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an input text that have `required=true` attribute, like below

```
<h:panelGrid columns=2>
   <h:panelGroup id="ccm">
      <p:inputText id="txtCCMNumber" value="#{setupView.selectedCCM}"
                 required="true" requiredMessage="Required">
          <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{setupView.handleLooseFocusCCMTextbox()}"
              update=":setupForm:ccm :setupForm:ccmMsg"/>
      </p:inputText>
      <h:outputText value="Duplicated" id="ccmExisted"
                 styleClass="ui-message-error ui-widget ui-corner-all"
                 rendered="#{setupView.ccmNameExisted}"/>
      <h:graphicImage id="ccmNotExist" url="resources/images/check-icon.png"
                    rendered="#{setupView.ccmNameUnique}"
                    width="18"/>
   </h:panelGroup>
   <p:message for="txtCCMNumber" id="ccmMsg" display="text"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

So my requirement is, if the value is empty, then it will display `Required`, since `required=true`, it should fail at Process Validation phase. If the value is unique, then display a `check` image, if duplicated, then display `Duplicated` text. The problem that I run into is, after I type something and tab away (let say I type something unique), it displays the `check` image, I then erase the text, and tab away again, now the `Required` text appear, but so is the `check` image. My theory is that, at the `Process validation` phase, it fail due to the value is empty, so at the update component phase, it does not invoke that method `handleLooseFocusCCMTextbox()` that will set the boolean `ccmNameUnique` to `false`. Is there a way to fix this?

**NOTE**: handleLooseFocusCCMTextbox() just turn the boolean value on and off to display the `check` image or `Duplicated` text.

**Answered**. Create Validator class, take out required=true

```
public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value)
        throws ValidatorException {
     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     SetupView setupView = (SetupView) context.getApplication().
           evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{setupView}", SetupView.class);
     if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()) {
        setupView.setCcmNameUnique(false);
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        message.setSummary("Error");
        message.setDetail("Required");
        //This will end up in <p:message>
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
     }
     String rootPath = setupView.getRootPath();
     File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
     if (rootFolder.exists() && rootFolder.canRead()) {
        List<String> folderNames = Arrays.asList(new File(rootPath).list());
        if (folderNames.contains(value.toString())) {
           setupView.setCcmNameUnique(false);
           FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
           message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
           message.setSummary("Error");
           message.setDetail("Duplicate");
           //This will end up in <p:message>
           throw new ValidatorException(message);
        } else {
           setupView.setCcmNameUnique(true);
        }
     } else {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Please check the root folder path as "
              + "we cannot seems to see it. The path is {0}", rootPath);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a validator instead of an action listener.

```
<p:inputText id="txtCCMNumber" value="#{setupView.selectedCCM}"
    required="true" requiredMessage="Required"
    validator="#{setupView.validateDuplicateCCM}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" update="ccm ccmMsg" />
</p:inputText>
```

with

```
public void validateDuplicateCCM(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()) {
        return; // Let required="true" handle.
    }

    // ...

    if (duplicate) {
        ((UIInput) component).setValid(false);
        ccmNameExisted = true;
        // I'd rather throw ValidatorException instead of above two lines here so that it ends up in <p:message>
    } else {
        ccmNameUnique = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I love your suggestion about `throw new ValidatorException()`. However, I still having the same problem. That if I dont type in anything, and tab away, it does not invoke `validateDuplicateCCM`. Therefore, if I type in something unique, and tab away, tick mark show up, and if I erase what I just type, and tab away the `Required` message show up, but the tick mark still there, because `validateDuplicateCCM` did not get invoked. Any idea BalusC? Same behavior if I switch to h:inputText

Comment: Oh yes, you've hit a bug in `validator` attribute. See this related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415059/validating-empty-fields-with-inline-validation-method-and-validator-class It will indeed not be invoked when the value is null. I'd move it into a normal `Validator` class which you declare by `<f:validator>`.

Comment: I see, however, I need to set `ccmNameUnique = true;` if no duplication found. `ccmNameUnique` is a variable in my view scoped managed bean `SetupView`. Can we inject managed bean into validator, BalusC?

Comment: You can only inject it if the validator class is registered as `@ManagedBean` and is been used as `<f:validator binding="#{validatorClassName}" />`. Alternatively it's available by `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`. As another alternative you could also try `rendered="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}"` on the check icon (this may only have undesireable side effects when also rendered by another inputs, so be careful with this).

Comment: I put the Validator as managed bean, but I still experienced two issues: 1. It still not get into my validator when the field is null. and 2. it does not set my `ccmNameUnique` to true. I post the code in my original post. can u take a look, BalusC

Comment: 1) That will happen when `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` context param is set to `false` in `web.xml`. Make sure that it's not `false` or just remove it. It defaults to `true`. 2) The `#{setupView}` seems to be a view scoped bean. The validator is created during restore view, when the view scoped beans aren't available yet. Instead, you get a brand new instance which is later overridden by the real restored view scoped beans. Use `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()` instead of `@ManagedProperty`.

Comment: Thank you, BalusC, `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()` works great. I have updated my code from my original post, however, I still having problem with invoking the validator method when the field is empty, I also post my web.xml on my original post as well, if you have some free time, will you please take a look at them. Thank you BalusC

Comment: I think I figure it out. After I remove `require=true` from my inputText, the it invoke my Validator even though the field is empty. Thank you for your help. It was your comment here that help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719739/jsf-converter-causes-validators-to-be-ignored

Comment: Oh right, totally overlooked that bit :) Yes, you'd need to take over the `required="true"` work in the validator, or to go ahead with `rendered="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}"` instead.